# Ubuntu 14.10 with Cinnamon desktop missing trash can icon on desktop

Tags: cinnamon

Missing Trash can desktop icon on Ubuntu 14.10 with Cinnamon GUI.  Is there a fix? I am a newbie.  Would upgrading to Ubuntu 15 be an easier solution?

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal go to home folder by using command cd ~ .

Delete files with the command rm as shown bellow and re-login. This should solve desktop problem when you relogin, since those files will be recreated with new configuration.

```
rm -rf .compiz .config .gconf .gnome .gnome2 .kde .gvfs .local
```